# Why the structure key value displaying twice like "Submit,Submit" in the form action page?

Tags: jquery, forms, coldfusion, jquery-validate, coldfusion-11

When I've added the form validation using the validate.js, Its validate fine and its displaying the validation message. But the input type="submit" value displaying twice in the action page structure.

for Illustrate, I've two .cfm files, the index.cfm having simple form with the validation and actionview.cfm having the <cfdump="#form#">. When I've submit the form in the submitHandler, the dumped structure displaying the submit button value is twice. Other form fields are displaying normally.

In the HTML and jQuery Validation code, in the index.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery validation plug-in - main demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
  <script src="../lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
      form.submit();
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  #commentForm {
    width: 500px;
  }
  #commentForm label {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #commentForm label.error, #commentForm input.submit {
    margin-left: 253px;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1 id="banner"><a href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/">jQuery Validation Plugin</a> Demo</h1>
    <p>Default submitHandler is set to submitting the form</p>
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="actionView.cfm">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
        <p>
          <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
          <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
          <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
          <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
          <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In actionView.cfm,

```
<cfdump var="#form#" />
```

here I've given the screenshots of the form & the dumped structure :

The sample form,

[image]

The Dumped Structure,

[image]

In the dumped structure, the Submit button value is "Submit,Submit" . But normally I've submitted the form its displaying the "Submit". I'm not sure why it's happening?

Is there anything I missed? I much appreciate if anybody explain why its displaying twice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you done any experimenting or troubleshooting at all?  What happens when you remove or change `value="Submit"`?  How about when you change `name="submit"`.  What does the ColdFusion documentation say is supposed to be displayed in that slot?

Comment: When using method="POST" nothing in the form gets added to the query string.

Comment: @Sparky When I've changed the value and name attributes, there is nothing happened, still the submit button value displaying as twice.

Comment: Yes @ScottStroz Correct, the form submit as POST method. So there is no changes to passing the field values as query string.

Comment: Take the jQuery Validation code out of the mix. Remove the calls to include the JS files and remove the input field validation attributes. Just submit the basic form and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @ScottStroz, referring to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data):  *"Whichever HTTP method (get or post) you choose, the server receives a string that will be parsed in order to get the data as a list of key/value pairs."*  ~ when I said "query string" I used incorrect terminology to refer to the data string that is sent to the server.  When there is a `name` on the submit, `&name=value` for the submit will be part of this data string.

Comment: Are you simply asking the question out of curiosity or is this causing some kind of problem?

Comment: @Miguel-F Without jQuery Validation code, the form scope displaying the single "Submit" in the form structure. The mentioned issue is not persists in the basic form.

Comment: jQuery Validate blocks the default submit, does the validation routine, then re-submits.  Maybe you're seeing both submit actions?  But again, **how is this a problem**?   There is [not one other complaint about this within all the thousands of jQuery Validate questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+%5Bcoldfusion%5D+is%3Aquestion) and [nothing on the developer's GitHub page](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+coldfusion).

Answer (score 0):

This is really comment, but it is too long. I just ran the code without jqueryvalidate and I got this:

[image: Screen shot of form and results]

**Suggestion**

Change

```
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

To

```
  <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for an explanation about *why* this is happening.  He never described a problem requiring a need to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Why this is happening is likely that the form is sending two values for a field named "Submit". The second value is apparently being injected by the jQuery validation routine, probably through `form.submit()`, which is also why changing to a `button` only submits once.

Comment: @James A Mohler, Thanks for the long comment. When I've checked with above <button></button> tag, Its throwing empty value for the submit key. And without the jQuery validation its working fine.

Comment: @Sparky Yes, I need to know why its happening. while I'm using jquery validator in my application, the form submission gives the twice value in the form structure.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the comment. When I've changed to <button> the structure not having the values. Its having empty value for the submit button in the structure.

Comment: @SathishChelladurai, ***why*** do you need to know?  ***How*** is this a problem?